# Loading pagination items with PHP makes them unclickable

Tags: php, jquery

I have this page:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="sideBar" id="leftSideBar">
                <ul id="menuList">
                    <li class="goDash">
                        <div class="menuImage active"><img src="assets/img/dashboard.png" /></div><span>Dashboard</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="goProd">
                        <div class="menuImage"><img src="assets/img/products.png" /></div><span>Products</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="goSale">
                        <div class="menuImage"><img src="assets/img/sales.png" /></div><span>Sales</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="content" id="mainContent">
                <div class="resultsPage dashBoard active">
                    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
                    <div class="overviewContent">
                        <div class="splitContainer">
                            <div class="leftCol">
                                <h3>Most revenue generated</h3>
                                <div class="leftContent">
                                    <div id="loading">
                                        <img id="loading-image" src="assets/img/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rightCol">
                                <h3>Most units sold</h3>
                                <div class="rightContent">
                                    <div id="loading">
                                        <img id="loading-image" src="assets/img/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="resultsPage productList">
                    <h2>Products</h2>
                    <div class="productFilters">
                        <form method="GET" action="">
                            <input type="text" id="searchTerms" placeholder="Search by title, sku, tsin id" />
                            <input id="searchProducts" type="submit" name="searchProducts" value="Search" />
                        </form>
                        <div class="prodPagination">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="productsContent">
                        <div class="pagination"></div>
                        <div class="prodContentData">
                            <div id="loading">
                                <img id="loading-image" src="assets/img/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pagination"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="resultsPage salesList">
                    <h2>Sales</h2>
                    <div class="salesFilters">
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            <label for="date1">Start Date</label>
                            <input id="startDate" type="date" name="date1" value="Start Date" placeholder="Start Date" value="" min="1997-01-01" max="2030-12-31" />
                            <label for="date2">End Date</label>
                            <input id="endDate" type="date" name="date2" value="End Date" placeholder="End Date" value="" min="01-01-2010" max="01-01-2030" />
                            <input id="filterSales" type="submit" name="getfiltered" value="Filter Results" />
                            <input id="clearSales" type="submit" name="clearsales" value="Reset Results" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class=" salesContent">
                        <div class="saleContentData">
                            <div id="loading">
                                <img id="loading-image" src="assets/img/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I generate a list of items based on the amount of pages there are for a result set. I want to use the list items as pagination links. So I load the items like so:

```
$result = getsales("https://api.someapi.com/v2/sales?page_size=" . $pagesize . "&page_number=" . $pageNum);
$sales_amount = $result['summary']['total'];
$items = $result['sales'];
$num_pages = (ceil($sales_amount / 100) * 100) / $pagesize;
$counter = 1;

echo "<div class='stats'><div class='totalpages'>There were " . $sales_amount . " sales in total. There are " . $num_pages . " pages.</div><div class='pagination'>
<ul id='pagesList'>";
for ($i = 1; $i < $num_pages + 1; $i++) {
    if ($i == $pageNum) {
        echo "<li class='$i active'>" . $i . "</li>";
    } else {
        echo "<li class='$i'>" . $i . "</li>";
    }
}
```

and they are loaded on the page like so:

```
<div class="stats">
    <div class="totalpages">There were 607 sales in total. There are 7 pages.</div>
        <div class="pagination">
            <ul id="pagesList">
                <li class="1 active">1</li>
                <li class="2">2</li>
                <li class="3">3</li>
                <li class="4">4</li>
                <li class="5">5</li>
                <li class="6">6</li>
                <li class="7">7</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery script to make the page go to the next page I put an alert on since it wasn't going to the next page. The click event is not triggered and the alert never displays:

```
  jQuery("#menuList li").click(function () {
    $(".resultsPage").removeClass("active");
    $(".menuImage, #menuList span").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).children(".menuImage, span").addClass("active");
    var which = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];
    if (which == "goDash") {
      $(".dashBoard").addClass("active");
      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "overview-left.php",
        success: function (data) {
          $(".leftContent").html(data);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
          $(".saleContentData").html(error);
        },
      });
      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "overview-right.php",
        success: function (data) {
          $(".rightContent").html(data);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
          $(".saleContentData").html(error);
        },
      });
    } else if (which == "goProd") {
      $(".productList").addClass("active");
      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "getproducts.php",
        success: function (data) {
          $(".prodContentData").html(data);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
          $(".saleContentData").html(error);
        },
      });
    } else if (which == "goSale") {
      $(".salesList").addClass("active");
      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "getsales.php",
        success: function (data) {
          $(".saleContentData").html(data);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
          $(".saleContentData").html(error);
        },
      });
      $("#pagesList li").click(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        alert();
      });
    }
  });
```

Why is the event not happening? There are no errors.
I have now isolated the code so it's as simple as possible. I have one call that loads two divs with content from two different php files. After loading the content I am still unable to click on anything and my script to make an alert show doesn't fire. My question is then is the page still loading and is it ever going to finish, or are the two blocks I load content into still loading and when will they ever finish? Here is my code that I isolated from the rest:

```
  //CLICK THE DASHBOARD BUTTON SO THE CONTENT CAN LOAD
  jQuery(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      jQuery(".goDash").click();
    }, 500);
  });

  //SHOW THE SPINNER WHILE A PAGE IS LOADING
  $(window).on("load", function () {
    $("#loading").hide();
  });

  $(".goDash").click(function () {
    $("#menuList li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".resultsPage").removeClass("active");
    $(".dashBoard").addClass("active");
    //LEFT COLUMN
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "overview-left.php",
      success: function (data) {
        $(".leftContent").html(data);
      },
      error: function (request, status, error) {
        $(".leftContent").html(error);
      },
    });
    //RIGHT COLUMN
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "overview-right.php",
      success: function (data) {
        $(".rightContent").html(data);
      },
      error: function (request, status, error) {
        $(".rightContent").html(error);
      },
    });
    $(function () {
      $(".num img").click(function () {
        alert("Works");
      });
    });
  });
```

The solution ended to be something really simple. I changed the:

```
$('#pagesList li").click(function(){
}
```

inside the handler doing the ajax call to

```
  $(document).on("click", "#pagesList li", function (e) {
    alert();
  });
```

completely on its own and now it works like intended. Amazing!!

Comment: Where is that jQuery script located on the page? That said, you had a `</div>` missing in your HTML sample. I took the liberty to add it.

Comment: But WHERE on the page is that call? In the header section? Please post the entire HTML that is output to your browser.

Comment: Your original code will not be executed at all, because there is no 'menuList' entry (at least not in the shown HTML) you could be clicking.

Comment: I now listed the entire page's html without the head and closing body and html tags

Comment: And where, on that page, is the JavaScript? Within the head, I'll assume? In that case, try wrapping your code in the ready handler I've described and see if that does it.

Comment: Also, for future questions, please refer to posting an [mre]. You initially gave us an incomplete snippet of code, which did not reflect the actual problem. I commend you for trying to break it down to the basic level, but did you ever actually run that snippet you gave us? And I mean just that snippet?

Comment: The jquery is loaded in the head. My custom js file is loaded in the footer.

Answer (score 1):

It wont work, because while you are loading the page, the li elements are not available.

**Edit 1**

After comments from @Refunic, if the script is loaded on the head or based on updated answer, the code is executed. Check by writing the this block of code outside the menusList click function

```
jQuery("#menuList li").click(function () {
  // All your codes here
})

$("#pagesList li").click(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        alert();
      });
```

Comment: I'm afraid I fail to see where Ajax is mentioned in the original post. Furthermore, it appears that your recommended solution is the very same thing he is doing right now, just more verbose. I agree with the 'not yet available' though.

Comment: you can see the line 1, result= which is calling an api... So it is my understanding it is a ajax call

Comment: That's PHP. AJAX would be on the JavaScript side. You can call a PHP script both synchronously and asynchronously.

Comment: Got it. My bad.. I did not notice it as mix of php and js.. I read it as javascript codes

Comment: I edited my question and added all the code I use to load the page with and the ajax calls. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

The snippet itself seems correct, which suggests, that the 'placement' might be the problem.

The browser evaluates script as it finds it, going from top to bottom, so if the snippet is above your list, it will fail to add the listener to anything, because the ID has not been declared yet.

Potential solutions include:

- Put the script below your list
- Wrap it into an 'ready' handler (preferred)

The `ready` handler looks like this:

```
$(function() {
  //yourScript
});
```

and will only be executed after the document has finished loading.

After edit by OP:

There is now a different problem.
The originally shown code is within the click handler of `#menuList`, which means that the handler will only be registered after you clicked any of the `#menuList` lines.

The upper handler will not function, because there is no container with the id `menuList` and the second handler will not function, because it is never executed.

Move the second handler outside of the upper handler and wrap it into the `ready` handler (described above) to make sure it will only be evaluated after the page finished loading.

Comment: I got it to work but the only way I could get it to work was to place the click event for the #menuList in the Ajax complete section

Comment: Well yes, of course. As Alaksander already correctly stated, neither the container nor the list items are available to the browser before your AJAX call returns. And that makes sense, really. Or can you put on sneakers that have yet to be delivered to your home address?

Comment: Trust me I am learning. I really appreciate the help I promise you.

Comment: But now I have another issue. Where do I put my code to make another ajax call so I can get the next page? I placed it in the complete section but it's not working and actually crashed the tab?

Comment: First off, I suggest trying to strip down your code to the bare minimum, which still causes the problem. That by itself may help you figure out what's wrong. Next: Don't put it into the 'complete' step, put it into the 'success' step. (There's no point in trying to attach event handlers anywhere, if the AJAX call was not successful, after all). As a final advice: Every major browser has a 'Debugging console' (Try hitting F12) which allows you to stop the execution of JavaScript and inspect variables. Debuggers are your friends. Use them.

Comment: Regarding the first step (that's called a [mre], by the way and will help us help you a lot), once you've done that, feel free to post another question with its contents. And tag it with JavaScript and JQuery, but not PHP. PHP has nothing to do with this at all. Many developers want too much at once and stumble somewhere along the way. Something to remember is 'KISS': 'Keep it stupidly simple'. And then work from there. One step at a time. And before you know it, you'll have built a solid application.

Comment: It was a very simple thing that solved it. You can see my question for the solution.